# What does "stand by a pledge" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

Does it mean "keep a pledge/promise". Or it means "stand beside the pledge"? If so ,it might be something like a metaphor..

Comment: Both. Because it is a metaphor. If I *stand beside* you through thick and thin, feast and famine; if I *stand beside* you on the field of battle when we meet the enemy; if I *stand beside* you no matter what, then I am faithful to you. I am loyal to you. To *stand beside* a pledge, I keep that pledge faithfully.

Answer (score 1):

The Merriam-Webster has three meanings for **[stand by](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand)**:

> 1:  to be or remain loyal or true to
>   *I stand by my **promise**.*
>   *He stood by a friend.*
>
> 2:  to be present
>   *We stood by and watched the fight.*
>
> 3:  to be or get ready to act
>   *I'll stand by to help.*

Since **plegde** is very similar to **promise**, the first sense fits best. So your guess expressed in

> Does it mean "keep a pledge/promise"?

is correct.